# Android: Using ViewPager with multiple dynamic Fragments

Tags: android, dynamic, android-viewpager, fragment

I am using a ViewPager to show 9 fragments. In each of these fragments, I want to just show a different picture. I want to use one single fragment layout, but dynamically add in the picture. Also, would like add a "Continue" button on the last fragment that when pressed will go to another activity.

How do I go about making a fragment layout dynamic?

**Main Activity**

```
public class StoryboardPageActivity extends FragmentActivity {
// The number of pages (wizard steps) to show in this demo.
private static final int NUM_PAGES = 9;

// The pager widget, which handles animation and allows swiping horizontally to access previous and next wizard steps.
private ViewPager mPager;

// The pager adapter, which provides the pages to the view pager widget.
private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_storyboard_page);

    // Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter.
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.storyboardPager);
    mPagerAdapter = new StoryboardPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
        // If the user is currently looking at the first step, allow the system to handle the
        // Back button. This calls finish() on this activity and pops the back stack.
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        // Otherwise, select the previous step.
        mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
    }
}

// A simple pager adapter that represents 5 fragment objects, in sequence.
private class StoryboardPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public StoryboardPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return StoryboardFragment.newInstance(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }
}
}
```

**Fragment**

```
public class StoryboardFragment extends Fragment {
private static final String KEY_POSITION = "position";

static StoryboardFragment newInstance(int position) {
    StoryboardFragment frag = new StoryboardFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();

    args.putInt(KEY_POSITION, position);
    frag.setArguments(args);

    return(frag);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_storyboard_page, container, false);

    ImageView image = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imgStoryboard);
    int position = getArguments().getInt(KEY_POSITION, -1);

    int[] images = {R.drawable.storyboard1, R.drawable.storyboard2, R.drawable.storyboard3,
                    R.drawable.storyboard4, R.drawable.storyboard5, R.drawable.storyboard6,
                    R.drawable.storyboard7, R.drawable.storyboard8, R.drawable.storyboard9};

    image.setImageResource(images[position]);

    return rootView;
}

}
```

**Fragment XML**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgStoryboard"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/storyboardSlide" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I go about making a fragment layout dynamic?

The same way you make any other "layout dynamic". If you want to put an image in an `ImageView`, call `setImageBitmap()` or `setImageDrawable()` or whatever. For example, the `PagerAdapter` could supply the `position` to the fragment (via a factory method), and the fragment could then know what image to load.

[This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/Fragments) demonstrates populating the `hint` of an `EditText` with a custom value based upon the page's `position`.

With respect to the "Continue" button, either have a separate fragment class for that (and appropriate smarts in your `PagerAdapter`, or always have the button in your layout, but set to `android:visibility="gone"` by default, toggling it via `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` for the fragment that needs it.

Comment: I altered my code after viewing your sample project, but when I go to the activity it doesn't load correctly. It doesn't crash, but it just doesn't load and reloads the Main Activity. I updated the code above. Can you give me a pointer or two?

Comment: @D-Rock: "it just doesn't load and reloads the Main Activity" -- I do not know what you mean by that, sorry. Other than making `images` be a `static final int[]`, I do not see any obvious problems with what you have here.

Comment: it was a problem with the high res images being in the regular `drawables` folder instead of the `xhdpi` folder. I had to search the error in the LogCat. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!